# How test uint from smartcontract with chai?

Tags: solidity, truffle-test, chai

In my solidity smartcontract, I have a function to return a uint value :

```
function getUserBalance(address userAddress, address tokenAddress)
        public
        view
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return _stakingUserBalance[userAddress][tokenAddress].stakedAmount;
    }

 I'm using chai for my test on js file, but it seems result is not a number :

let amountForSpenderBeforeWithdraw = await AlyraStackingInstance.getUserBalance(spender, DaiInstance.address);
... // some code
 let amountForSpenderAfterWithdraw = await AlyraStackingInstance.getUserBalance(spender, DaiInstance.address);   

expect(amountForSpenderBeforeWithdraw).to.be.greaterThan(amountForSpenderAfterWithdraw);
```

When I launch my test with `truffle test`, my test return following error :

```
AssertionError: expected 9 to be a number or a date
```

When I replace with hard coded value, test is ok. When I write values in console, values are ok.
Is it a cast problem ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'd recommend to use [OpenZeppelin Test Helpers](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-test-helpers). It uses chai-bn for handling the BN returned by web3 in a more amenable way.

Answer (score 2):

Self answer :

```
expect(parseInt(amountForSpenderBeforeWithdraw)).to.be.greaterThan(parseInt(amountForSpenderAfterWithdraw));
```